# Do I need to unsubscribe manually? - Angular 8

Tags: angular, observable, angular8, subscribe

I have simple question.
Do I need to unsubscribe manually or Angular is doing that for me or if does't how to understand what is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: you have to unsubscribe manually

Comment: @Supercool - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im most cases - yes. You have to unsubscribe almost any time when you make a subscription. There are some exceptions when you don't have to do this though, like subscribing to http service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You need to unsubscribe there are some exceptions like `route` related observable.

You can find here different ways of unsubscribing https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-ways-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-in-angular-ab912819a78f

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an `async` pipe Angular handles the subscription, subscribing and unsubscribing for you within the component life cycle.

If you have subscribed within a component, you need to unsubscribe if the observable does not complete.

Here is a very [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription) post on the subject (pun intended!).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in many cases. If you don't do it it can lead to memory leakage. For example, it's normal to subscribe to an observable in `ngOnInt()` and to   unsubscribe in  `ngOnDestroy()` in the component.

As mentioned before it's not always you have to unsubscribe manually, for example when using some specific operators like `take`. If you use `async` in the template, manually unsubscribing is not necessary. Furthermore, it is also not necessary to unsubscribe Observables in services that are registered once.